# How can i create a condition to know if i have information in other table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm trying to create a condition in my condition to check if a policy has an insurance

My tables:

```
|policies|
  |id|    |num_policy|  
   1        1234          
   2        5678           
   3        9123          
   4        4567           

|insurances|
  |id|  |policy_id|     |net_ensurance|
   1       1                1000
```

This is what I'm trying to do

```
If policy has an insurance do
  @condition
else
  nothing
end
```

Here is my model:

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :insurances
end

class Insurance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :policy
end
```

Here is my controller:

```
  if Policy.has_insurance?
   @search = Policy.find(:all,:conditions =>['deleted = 0'])
  else
   @search= "nothing"
  end
```

Please somebody can help me with this?

I will really appreciate help

Comment: Are you trying to find out whether one policy record has an insurance, or are you trying to find all policies with an insurance?

Comment: yes if a policy record has an insurance.Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to find if a **particular** Policy has an associated insurance.

What about doing this:

```
if @policy.insurances.size > 0
 # that policy have insurances
else
 # that policy does not have insurances
end
```

Comment: I'm trying to do it in my controller because when i try to export i'm having "undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass" because i don't have an insurance created

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911005/issue-exporting-nil-values  ...I have a bit of information of what i'm trying to do

Comment: ```@policy``` is whatever Policiy object you want to work on. For example... ```@policy = Policy.first```

Comment: I got undefined method `insurances' for #<Array:0x7f102daa6ec0>